# Finding if a date is on a range of two weekends between another date

Tags: algorithm, date, methods

I'm making a application that give discounts for users and one of the discounts is given on his birthday. As is really hard to use a discount only on your birthday, we decide to give the discount all the week, including both weekends around.

#### Some rules

- Given the birth date, the discount will start on the previous friday of the birthday;
- The discount will end 10 days after the start, on the sunday;
- If the birthday it's on a friday, still get the last friday before this one;

Ok, so we need a method that receive the `birthdayDate` and the `todayDate` and return true or false telling if the date is on the birthday range.

#### The problem

Everything seens fine until you start to look at the dates near the change of the year.
**If your birthday is on December 31 of 2018, you can use the discount on January 6 of 2019, the same way, if your birthday is on January 1 of 2019, on December 28 of 2018 you already can use the discount.**
So look only to the birthday of current year is not enough and, as the days of the week change every year, the last friday of your birthday this year will not be same day on the next one.

There is a elegant way to easily find this range and create the method returning true or false?

The real problem is find which birthday is relevant birthday, as you can receive the discount after your last birthday and before your next birthday.

The original code is in PHP, but as it's a algorithm problem, I can accept answers in any language

#### Test cases

```
| Today             | Birth             | Output |
|-------------------|-------------------|:------:|
| February 15, 2019 | February 22, 2000 | true   |
| February 24, 2019 | February 22, 2000 | true   |
| February 25, 2019 | February 22, 2000 | false  |
| December 28, 2018 | January 03, 2000  | true   |
| December 27, 2018 | January 03, 2000  | false  |
| December 27, 2019 | January 03, 2000  | true   |
| January 01, 2019  | January 03, 2000  | true   |
| January 01, 2019  | December 31, 2000 | true   |
| January 01, 2019  | December 28, 2000 | false  |
```

Comment: It sounds like it's simply "Find the previous Friday before the relevant birthday." That's pretty easy to do in many languages. Could you show what you've already tried? I don't see why dates near the change of year would actually be particularly relevant here. If it's to do with which birthday is the relevant birthday, it would be helpful if you could be more specific about this. It would be great if you could list all the inputs (e.g. current date, birthday) and expected output.

Comment: Find the last friday is really simple, and most of the languages already have a method for it. The problem is: which birthday you need to find the last friday? Maybe your next birthday is already giving you the discount. Maybe is the last one.

I'll add more cases to the question.

Comment: It's hard to know what you mean by "which birthday you need" when we don't know what the expected output is. Are you trying to find out whether the discount should be valid *today*? Or a period to show a user? If you could pin this down to a specific language with a [mcve] that shows what you've tried so far, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: I've added some test cases. I'm reviewing the text to make it more clear.

Comment: Okay, those test cases definitely make it easier to help. I'll write up an answer using C# as the implementation language, but explain what it's doing too.

Comment: (Leap years are likely to be a bit of a pain, btw.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some C# code using my [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org) library that passes all the tests you've specified.

The basic idea is simple:

- Go back three months from today
- Find the birthday after that date
- Construct the discount period around that birthday
- Check whether today's date is in that period

The choice of three months is somewhat arbitrary; it's just intended to get around the case where you've *just* had a birthday. (It's possible that anything more than 10 days and less than 355 days would be fine. I just find 3 months easier to reason about.)

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        RunTest("2019-02-15", "2000-02-22", true);
        RunTest("2019-02-24", "2000-02-22", true);
        RunTest("2019-02-25", "2000-02-22", false);
        RunTest("2018-12-28", "2000-01-03", true);
        RunTest("2019-01-01", "2000-01-03", true);
        RunTest("2018-12-27", "2000-01-03", false);
        RunTest("2019-12-27", "2000-01-03", true);
    }

    static void RunTest(string todayText, string birthdayText, bool expectedResult)
    {
        var pattern = LocalDatePattern.Iso;
        RunTest(pattern.Parse(todayText).Value,
                pattern.Parse(birthdayText).Value,
                expectedResult);               
    }

    static void RunTest(LocalDate today, LocalDate birthday, bool expectedResult)
    {
        // Work out "the birthday that comes after 3 months ago".
        // That can be:
        // - A recent birthday before the closest birthday discount period,
        //   in which case the *next* birthday will be after the current closest
        //   discount period
        // - A birthday *in* the current closest birthday discount period
        // - A birthday *after* the current closest birthday discount period,
        //   in which case the *previous* birthday was before the current
        //   closest discount period
        LocalDate threeMonthsAgo = today.PlusMonths(-3);
        int ageThreeMonthsAgo = Period.Between(birthday, threeMonthsAgo).Years;

        // Note: this will use Feb 28th for a Feb 29th birthday in a non leap year.
        LocalDate relevantBirthday = birthday.PlusYears(ageThreeMonthsAgo + 1);

        // Find the strictly-previous Friday to start the discount interval
        LocalDate discountStart = relevantBirthday.With(DateAdjusters.Previous(IsoDayOfWeek.Friday));        
        LocalDate discountEndInclusive = discountStart.PlusDays(9);
        DateInterval discountInterval = new DateInterval(discountStart, discountEndInclusive);

        bool actualResult = discountInterval.Contains(today);
        Console.WriteLine($"{today} / {birthday} / {(actualResult == expectedResult ? "PASS" : "FAIL")}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

proposal solution (using JS and timestamps)

```js
// Helper constants
const day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
const friday = 5
const $input = document.getElementById('datepicker')
const $result = document.getElementById('result')
const $tests = document.getElementById('tests')

// Generate the period based on birthday and now (optional)
function getPeriod(birthday, today) {
  const now = new Date(today || new Date())
  // reset to start at 00:00
  now.setHours(0)
  now.setMinutes(0)
  now.setMilliseconds(0)

  // Available beggining date
  const begin = new Date(now - (10 * day))
  birthday = new Date(birthday)
  // fix birthday year
  birthday.setFullYear(begin.getFullYear())
  
  // if it already passed, jump to next year
  if (birthday < begin)
    birthday.setFullYear(birthday.getFullYear() + 1)

  // Start date
  const start = new Date(birthday)
  
  // if the birthday is already on friday, jump to previous friday (3th condition) 
  if(start.getDay() === friday)
    start.setTime(start.getTime() - (day * 7))

  // go to the last friday
  while (start.getDay() !== friday) 
    start.setTime(start.getTime() - day)
  // return found date + 10 days
  return [start, new Date(start.getTime() + (10 * day)-1)]
}


function calculatePeriod() {
  const birthday = $input.value
  const [begin, end] = getPeriod(birthday)
  $result.innerHTML = begin.toString() + '<br>' + end.toString()
}


const testCases = [
  ['February 15, 2019', 'February 22, 2000'],
  ['February 24, 2019', 'February 22, 2000'],
  ['February 25, 2019', 'February 22, 2000'],
  ['December 28, 2018', 'January 03, 2000'],
  ['December 27, 2018', 'January 03, 2000'],
  ['December 27, 2019', 'January 03, 2000'],
  ['January 01, 2019 ', 'January 03, 2000'],
  ['January 01, 2019 ', 'December 31, 2000'],
  ['January 01, 2019 ', 'December 28, 2000'],
]

testCases.map(([now, birthday]) => {
  const [begin, end] = getPeriod(birthday, now)
  $tests.innerHTML += `BIRTH: ${birthday}<br>NOW:   ${now}<br>BEGIN: ${begin}<br>END  : ${end}<br><br>`
})
```

```html
<h3>Select an date</h3>
<input type="date" id="datepicker" value="2019-01-01"/>
<button onclick="calculatePeriod()">Calculate</button>

<p>Result: <pre id="result">...</pre></p>
<hr />

<h3>Tests</h3>
<pre id="tests"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the same solution from Jon Skeet, but in PHP using Carbon.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

class UserBirthdayTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * Setup this test
     */
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
    }

    /**
     * Test create methods on basic CRUDs controllers
     */
    public function testCreate()
    {
        $this->validate("2019-02-15", "2000-02-22", true);
        $this->validate("2019-02-24", "2000-02-22", true);
        $this->validate("2019-02-25", "2000-02-22", false);
        $this->validate("2018-12-28", "2000-01-03", true);
        $this->validate("2019-01-01", "2000-01-03", true);
        $this->validate("2018-12-27", "2000-01-03", false);
        $this->validate("2019-12-27", "2000-01-03", true);
    }

    /**
     * @param \PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult $today
     * @param $birthday
     * @param $expectedResult
     * @return \PHPUnit\Framework\TestResult|void
     */
    public function validate($today, $birthday, $expectedResult)
    {
        $today = new Carbon($today);
        $birthday = new Carbon($birthday);

        // closest discount period
        $threeMonthsAgo = (new Carbon($today))->subMonth(3);

        $ageThreeMonthsAgo = $birthday->diffInYears($threeMonthsAgo);

        // Note: this will use Feb 28th for a Feb 29th birthday in a non leap year.
        $relevantBirthday = $birthday->addYears($ageThreeMonthsAgo + 1);

        // Find the strictly-previous Friday to start the discount interval
        $discountStart = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime('last friday', $relevantBirthday->timestamp));
        $discountEndInclusive = (new Carbon($discountStart))->addDays(9);

        $actualResult = $today->greaterThanOrEqualTo($discountStart) && $today->lessThanOrEqualTo($discountEndInclusive); // between($discountStart, $discountEndInclusive, false);

        $this->assertEquals($expectedResult, $actualResult);
    }
}
```